# update google map position via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can update the google map marker position but I cannot update the google map position. It does not centres the map to the latitude and longitude position given

```
var myLatlng;
var map;
var infowindow;
var latitude;
var longtitude;
var marker;

loadMap();
function loadMap()
{
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.91252, -1.37664);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemaps"), mapOptions);
    var contentString = '<h5>The Mew </h5>';

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: "The Mew",
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}

function updatePosition()
{
    latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
    longtitude = document.getElementById('longtitude');
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longtitude);
    marker.setPosition(myLatlng);
    map.setCenter(myLatlng);
}



  <input type="text" id="latitude" />
   <input type="text" id="longtitude" />
   <a onclick="updatePosition()" >update </a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818984/google-map-api-v3-center-zoom-on-displayed-markers

Comment: @edcs plz read the question. They are different questions

Comment: Don't just call `loadMap` directly.  Instead add a google event listener for the window to load, which then calls it: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadMap);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `updatePosition` the information you're assigning to latitude and longitude are the *DOM nodes* of those input fields but you want to assign the *value* of those inputs instead. Also, you need to ensure that the *text* you're grabbing from those values is converted to a *number* for `LatLng` to accept them properly. You can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for that. Don't forget the radix.

```
function updatePosition() {
  latitude = parseInt(document.getElementById('latitude').value, 10);
  longtitude = parseInt(document.getElementById('longtitude').value, 10);
  myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longtitude);
  marker.setPosition(myLatlng);
  map.setCenter(myLatlng);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to get values of inputs

```
function updatePosition()
 {
   var lat= $('#latitude').val();
   var lng= $('#longtitude').val();
   myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
   marker.setPosition(myLatlng);
   map.setCenter(myLatlng);
 }
```

and in Javascript you have to use [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) which will parse string and return a integer

```
  lat = parseInt(document.getElementById('latitude').value,10);
  lng = parseInt(document.getElementById('longtitude').value,10);
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7ADWP/)

Comment: If the OP isn't using jQuery anywhere else in the code, why would they use it here?

Comment: JQuery is simply a specific library of JavaScript code and its so easy to use and extremely powerful.