# Google maps link default zoom

Tags: google-maps

In the past, it was possible to append `&z=12` to google maps link to force given zoom. However it is no longer working in new google maps. I did a google search first, found lots of links even on stackoverflow, but none provided any solution for this.

I am creating google maps link this way:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/Praha,+Czech+Republic
```

This way it zooms right at the location, not country map. How do I get the country map (decreased default zoom)? I will answer my own question right away.

Comment: Try the solution in this link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818984/google-map-api-v3-center-zoom-on-displayed-markers!!

Answer (score 0):

To get the best link with the entire country zoomed out, one has to find out GPS coordinates of the center of the country, and then append it to the link, and specify zoom as follows:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/Praha,+Czech+Republic/@49.5691985,15.4303608,7z/
```

This shows entire country on google map, zoomed to the center point located at @49.5691985,15.4303608, zoom factor 7. I hope somebody will find this useful.

Comment: Your solution requires a specific size of the browser-window.